# Type 'Observable<DocumentData[]>' is not assignable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm new to angular and to firebase and I try to do a simple program using the example of the angular/fire library:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Firestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface Item {
  name: string
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of item$ | async">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'firetest2812';
  item$: Observable<Item[]>;
  constructor(firestore: Firestore) {
    const collect = collection(firestore, 'items');
    this.item$ = collectionData(collect);
  }
}
```

While compiling I got these error: " Error: src/app/app.component.ts:24:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<DocumentData[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Item[]>'. "

Can someone tell me what's wrong please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by casting like this :

```
 this.item$ = collectionData(collect) as Observable<Item[]>
```

**Or in a good way**

You can use **AngularFirestore** as firestore type instead of ***Firestore***

You will get something like this

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {AngularFirestore} from "@angular/fire/compat/firestore";


interface Item {
  name: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of item$ | async">
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'firetest2812';
  item$: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.item$ = firestore.collection<Item>("items").valueChanges();

  }
}
```

Comment: do you know if there is a reason to don't have this in official documentation?

Comment: I have no idea why Firestore is used in their example instead of AngularFirestore in their base example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your interface as type to the `collection` function.

```js
 const collect = collection<Item>(firestore, 'items');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work "  Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

24     const collect = collection<Item>(firestore, 'items'); "

Comment: Can you try providing type on collectionData instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the generic type in the `collectionData()` function since you specified the `item$` Observable type as `Item[]` in the property.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'firetest2812';
  item$: Observable<Item[]>;
  constructor(firestore: Firestore) {
    const collect = collection(firestore, 'items');
    // Specify the type here
    this.item$ = collectionData<Item>(collect);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, the lazy answer is do use `any`.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'firetest2812';
  item$: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(firestore: Firestore) {
    const collect = collection(firestore, 'items');
    // Specify the type here
    this.item$ = collectionData(collect);
  }
}
```